# How to add a partiular version to the roles file in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, chefspec

I have the created a role file with the below contents.

```
name "Windows_role_150719"
description "Windows_role_150719"

run_list "recipe[deep-sec1]",
"recipe[deep-sec1::install]",
"recipe[deep-sec1::activate]"

override_attributes({
})
```

The deep-sec1::install & deep-sec1::activate has multiple versions. 
Like v1, v2, v3, v4, v5

In the roles file how can i specify the version that needs to be installed on the particular node rather than being the latest which is v5.

By default when i upload the role using the "knife role from file command" it takes the latest version and not v2 which i ideally want to apply on the node.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

specifying (pinning\locking) a [cookbook version](https://docs.chef.io/cookbook_versioning.html) is done using an [environment](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html), and you associate each node with an environment.

when the chef-client run will start on a node, the cookbooks will be synchronized to the node fullfilling the (cookbook) constraints specified in the environment which the node belongs to.